# Linking Website Account with Facebook Messenger Bot

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-accounts, facebook-messenger

I want to add a login button to my bot so users can log in and I can store and extract a unique id (that I provide) for that user that I can use later to grab specific information. I'm having trouble following [Facebook's documentation for this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking).

Right now I have generated a login button that when pressed links to my login page via an external pop up browser but right now when logged in, the page just redirects to my website. I also noticed that the URL that is popped up provides an account linking token but i'm not really sure what to do with this.

Do I have to write some code on my end to work with this interface or am I missing something? Also how can I get it so that the external browser closes after a user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to write some code on your end to create a page and backend code that can:

1) Lookup PSID on FB Graph (Optional)
2) Do other account stuff (Optional)
3) Use redirect_uri to send the user back into the bot

The user has to click 'done' after Facebook shows the 'account linking successful' window.